# Fast way to add/append to a large file

Tags: bash, large-files

I have a bash script that reads a rather large file, line by line, and for each line does some processing and writes the results to another file. Currently I am using **`echo`** to append to the end of the result file, but as the size of the file grows, this gets slower and slower. So my question is what is a fast way to append lines to a large file?

The order by which the lines are added to the file is irrelevant to me, so I am open to adding to the **beginning** or the **end** or any **random** location in the file. I am also running the script on a server with large amounts of RAM, so if holding the results in a variable and writing the whole thing at the end is faster, that works for me as well.

Actually there are 2 scripts, I have put a sample of each here (they are part of the actual script, but I removed some parts for the sake of simplicity.

```
while read line
do
    projectName=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1`
    filepath=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2`
    numbers=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f3`
    linestart=`echo $numbers | cut -d: -f2`
    length=`echo $numbers | cut -d: -f3`
    lang=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f9`
    cloneID=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f10`
    cloneSubID=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f11`
    minToken=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f12`
    stride=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f13`
    similarity=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f14`
    currentLine=$linestart
    endLine=$((linestart + length))
    while [ $currentLine -lt $endLine ];
    do
        echo "$projectName, $filepath, $lang, $linestart, $currentLine, $cloneID, $cloneSubID, $minToken, $stride, $similarity"
        currentLine=$((currentLine + 1))
    done
done < $filename
```

The above code I use like this: `./script filename > outputfile`

And the second script is like this:

```
while read -r line;
do
    echo "$line" | grep -q FILE
    if [ $? = 0 ];
    then
        if [[ $line = *"$pattern"* ]];
        then
            line2=`echo "${line//$pattern1/$sub1}" | sed "s#^[^$sub1]*##"`
            newFilePath=`echo "${line2//$pattern2/$sub2}"`
            projectName=`echo $newFilePath | sed 's#/.*##'`
            localProjectPath=`echo $newFilePath | sed 's#^[^/]*##' | sed 's#/##'`
            cloneID=$cloneCounter
            revisedFile="revised-$postClusterFile-$projectName"
            overallRevisedFile="$cluster_dir/revised-overall-post-cluster"
            echo $projectName $localProjectPath $lang $cloneID $cloneSubID $minToken $stride $similarity >> $overallRevisedFile
            cloneSubID=$((cloneSubID + 1))
        fi
    fi
done < $cluster_dir/$postClusterFile
```

The second code is used like: `./script input output`

---

Update

OK, apparently the main culprit was the extensive use of backticks.
The first script was heavily modified and now runs in in 2 minutes vs previous run time of 50 minutes. I am completely happy with it. Thanks to @BinaryZebra for the following Code:

```
while read -r projectName filepath numbers a a a a a lang cloneID cloneSubID minToken stride similarity;
do
    IFS=':' read -r a linestart length <<<"$numbers"
    currentLine=$linestart
    endLine=$((linestart + length))

    while [ $currentLine -lt $endLine ]; do
        echo "$projectName, $filepath, $lang, $linestart, $currentLine, $cloneID, $cloneSubID, $minToken, $stride, $similarity"
        currentLine=$((currentLine + 1))
    done
done < $filename >>$outputfile
```

But for the second script, I have modified it to look something like this (I also included a bit more of the actual script here):

```
while read -r line;
do
  echo "$line" | grep -q FILE
  if [ $? = 0 ];
  then
    if [[ $line = *"$pattern"* ]];
    then
      IFS=$'\t' read -r a a filetest  <<< "$line"
      filetest="${filetest#*$pattern1}"
      projectName="${filetest%%/*}"
      localProjectPath="${filetest#*/}"
      cloneID=$cloneCounter
      revisedFile="revised-$postClusterFile-$projectName"
      echo $projectName $localProjectPath $lang $cloneID $cloneSubID $minToken $stride $similarity
      cloneSubID=$((cloneSubID + 1))
    fi
  else
    echo "This is a line: $line" | grep -q \n
    if [ $? = 0 ];
    then
       cloneCounter=$((cloneCounter + 1))
       cloneSubID=0
    fi
  fi
done < $cluster_dir/$postClusterFile >> $overallRevisedFile
```

It is much faster than before: 7 minutes vs. 20 minutes, but I need it to be still faster, and I still feel the slowdown in larger tests. It has been running for roughly 24 hours and the output size is almost 200MB at this moment. I am expecting the output file to be roughly 3GB so this may take 2 weeks which I cannot afford. The size/growth of the output is also non-linear, slowing down as time passes.

Is there any more I can do or is it just what it is?

Comment: How are you appending exactly? `echo new stuff >> file`? That should not be slow... combining many `echo` calls into one would still help, of course.

Comment: yes @frostschutz, that is how I am doing it. It is much fast at the beginning, but once you get to 100MB+, it is rather slower. So you are claiming that appending to the end of the file is not dependent on file size?

Comment: _I have a bash script that reads a rather large file, line by line, and for each line does some processing_ - if you're using `while..read` for that, good luck making it any faster... Most likely a _XY problem_...

Comment: @don_crissti, I am doing that, but reading is not my bottle neck. I am reading just 1 static file (i.e. the file I read from is not changed by my script). so each iteration should roughly take the same amount of time, but as the output file grows, the `echo stuff >> file` takes longer which is the problem.

Comment: How do you know, that it is the append that is the problem. Can you try changing code to `echo stuff >> /dev/null` and re-running the speed-test.

Comment: All we can tell from your description is that you seem to be doing the right thing. Appending to a file takes about constant time. Inserting data anywhere else would require rewriting the whole file, so would take longer for longer files. If you want help, post [complete code that would allow us to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695257/performance-issues-in-writing-to-large-files may be related.

Comment: What OS? what file-system?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, and my file-system is ext4. The disks on this machine have a RAID 6 configuration (or so I was told).

Comment: Use something else than bash, e.g. `awk`, or Python, or C. Perhaps consider putting your data in [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) etc...

Comment: You're using `grep` on a single line at a time to see whether the line contains a string?  That's an unnecessary fork and exec.  Try changing `echo "$line" | grep -q FILE` / `if [ $? = 0 ]`  to  `if [[ $line = *FILE* ]]`.  And what do you think `echo "This is a line: $line" | grep -q \n` does?  I think it tests whether `This is a line: $line` contains an `n` — and, of course, it always does.

Comment: Thank you so much @G-Man, That suggestion shrunk run time from roughly 16 times!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some ideas:
1.- Instead of calling cut repeatedly on each line, take advantage of read.
The list of variables cut on `' '` are:

```
projectName 1
filepath 2
numbers 3
lang 9
cloneID 10
cloneSubID 11
minToken 12
stride 13
similarity 14
```

That could be done directly by read as this:

```
while read -r projectName filepath numbers a a a a a lang cloneID cloneSubID minToken stride similarity;
```

a longer line, but shorter processing time. Variable a is just to fill up the space of unused values.

2.- The re-processing of variable numbers to be divided by ':' could be done as this (your question is tagged bash):

```
IFS=':' read -r a linestart length <<<"$numbers"
```

Which brings the code down to:

```
while read -r projectName filepath numbers a a a a a lang cloneID cloneSubID minToken stride similarity;
do
    IFS=':' read -r a linestart length <<<"$numbers"

    currentLine=$linestart
    endLine=$((linestart + length))

    while [ $currentLine -lt $endLine ]; do
        echo "$projectName, $filepath, $lang, $linestart, $currentLine, $cloneID, $cloneSubID, $minToken, $stride, $similarity"
        currentLine=$((currentLine + 1))
    done
done < $filename >>$outputfile
```

3.- As for the second script, there is no description of what vars sub1 and/or sub2 are.

4.- In general, if you could split the one script in a series of smaller scripts, then you could time each one to find where is the time-consuming area.

5.- And, as some other answer recommend, placing the file (and all intermediary results) in a memory partition will make things faster on the first file read. Subsequent executions of the script will read from the cache in memory, hiding any improvement. [This guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/) should help.

Comment: Thank you. It worked wonderfully, run-time reduced from 50 mins to 2 mins.

Comment: @MohammadGharehyazie You're welcome. The second script could improve by using awk instead of bash, but the gains will no be so dramatic. Glad to be of help.

Comment: I have used bash internals to improve the second script. Do you see any room for improvements?

Comment: @MohammadGharehyazie Well, you do need a big change to reduce your estimate of 2 weeks to some hours. For sure, shell magic will not get you there. You could use sh instead of bash, to gain some speed. But for the size of the problem you do need to change to some other language. I named awk, it is designed to deal with text files. I am sure that some perl magic could help you also. But really, for the size of the problem you comment, the only reasonable answer for speed is C. Could you write code on any of those options?.

Comment: I certainly can, but I have to get myself warmed up first which take a while. I am not good in bash either (this is not my code though, I am left with legacy code). So you believe if I coded this in C it would be meaningfully faster?

Comment: Correctly coded C will be substantially faster, as fast as code could be. However, it is NOT an easy language to code on, you do need experience to be an efficient C coder. Maybe start with awk, it is a simpler language. Perl is a somewhat cousin of awk, but it is far more complex.

Comment: But I am shooting in the dark, I have no idea of what is it that you are processing, nor why is it so big. The code in the script 2 is still quite obscure and I have no real clue of what is it doing. So, I am (as several other users also have already stated) unable to find a reasonable answer. That is as far as I could go.

Comment: Here is a brief decription of what my code does. I can put up the whole script too but it requires several other files to run properly:

Read input file (which is output of a program) line by line,
if line is not empty, do some parsing, output to outputfile
else do some other parsing
done.

Comment: It basically parses an ugly file to a more clear and clarified format. That is it.

Comment: +1 for not calling `cut` each line.  my script suffered from similar slowdown, particularly from calling `$(cut -c 2 <<< "$line")` on each loop.  replacing this with parameter expansion `${line:1:1}` sped up execution immensely.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the file in /dev/shm, which is a ram-resided filesystem. It will boost your access speed both for read n write from/to file. Finally you may copy the file from shm to the permanent disk partition.

Comment: I tried and timed the script , but it only made a difference of 30 seconds in an overall run time of 49 minutes. But thank you.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me about /dev/shm. @MohammadGharehyazie sounds like your operation probably isn't disk-bound. You could probably increase performance by leveraging more CPU power and RAM by parallelizing the process.

Answer (score 2):

*One* problem here is that you do:

```
while : loop
do    : processing
      echo "$results" >>output
done  <input
```

This will result in minutely increasing execution time per iteration simply because the *`output`* is repeatedly *`open()`*ed at a slightly larger offset than it was the last time. I say *minutely* because there is *virtually* no difference in how long it takes to open a file at an earlier offset than at a later one, but there is *some*. And every time you *`open()`* `O_APPEND` you do so at a slightly further position than ypu did the last time. How long this takes to do depends on the disk config/underlying filesystem but I think it is fairly reasonable to assume that there will be *some* cost per occurrence, and that it will increase to some degree as the filesize also does.

What you probably should do instead is just one *`open()`* and to maintain the *`write()`* descriptor for the life of the loop. You might do such a thing like:

```sh
while : loop
do    : processing
      echo "$results"
done  <input >>output
```

This may not be the primary cause. It is the most obvious cause to me that might be directly related to increasing iterations, but there's a lot going on in your loop that probably shouldn't be. You almost definitely should not be doing 10 or more subshelled data evaluations per loop iteration. Best practice would be to do zero of those - usually if you can't efficiently construct a self-contained shell loop in such a way that it can execute wholly from start to finish without a fork, then you sprobably shouldn't be doing one at all.

You should instead focus your evaluations with tools which can manage it by slicing a piece here and a piece there in *serial* - which is how well-written pipeline should work - rather than spidering off many dead-end loops per loop iteration. Try to think of it like this:

```
input |
(Single app single loop) |
(Single app single loop) |
(Single app single loop) |
output
```

That's a pipeline where each of those single loops executes concurrently tp the one before it.

But you do rather:

```
input |
(Single app \
        (input slice|single app single loop);
        (input slice|single app single loop);
        (input slice|single app single loop);
 single loop) |
 output
```

That's how shell loops which rely on subshells work. That's not efficient by any means, and isn't helped that the input and output are probably unbuffered as well.

Subshells are not evil - they're a convenient means of containing an evaluation context. But it is almost always best to apply them before or after a loop of any kind as is necessary to prepare or condition input or output to better *suit a more efficient loop*. Don't do them in the loop, but take the time to set it up properly first, and then do no more once you've got started.

Comment: Your "minute increase": because of potential indirection through increasing levels of file pointer blocks? If not, I'm not clear why opening at byte offset 1 should be any different to byte offset 100,000?

Answer (score 1):

- Large files can be slightly slower to work with than small files —
  and I don't mean just because there's more data. 
  If file *B* is 1000 times the size of file *A*,
  then it may take 1001 or 1002 times as long to process in its entirety.
- Reopening the output file (and seeking to the end) on each iteration
  is a slight performance drain.  Try changing your second script to do

  ```
  while read -r line
  do
        ︙
              echo "$projectName $localProjectPath … $stride $similarity"
        ︙
  done < "$cluster_dir/$postClusterFile" >> "$overallRevisedFile"
  ```

  If you're not adding content
  to a previously existing `$overallRevisedFile` file,
  just say `> "$overallRevisedFile"` (instead of `>>`) on the `done` line.

  But I wouldn't expect that to make a big difference.
- If you don't want to redirect the standard output for your entire loop,
  you can do something like

  ```
  while read -r line
  do
        ︙
              echo "$projectName $localProjectPath … $stride $similarity" >&3
        ︙
  done < "$cluster_dir/$postClusterFile"  3>> "$overallRevisedFile"
  ```

  If you need access to the output file in more than just a loop, do

  ```
  exec 3>> "$overallRevisedFile"
  while read -r line
  do
        ︙
              echo "$projectName $localProjectPath … $stride $similarity" >&3
        ︙
  done < "$cluster_dir/$postClusterFile"
     ︙
  (other code) >&3
     ︙
  exec 3>&-
  ```
- A few things that might make your script better, but not necessarily faster:

  - You should always quote your shell variable references
    (e.g., `"$line"`, `"$cluster_dir"`, `"$postClusterFile"`,
    and `"$overallRevisedFile"`)
    unless you have a good reason not to,
    and you’re *sure* you know what you’re doing.
  - `$(command)` is pretty much equivalent
    to `` `command` `` and is widely considered to be more readable.
  - You've got (at least) one `echo` that you don't need.

    ```
    newFilePath=`echo "${line2//$pattern2/$sub2}"`
    ```

    can be simplified to

    ```
    newFilePath="${line2//$pattern2/$sub2}"
    ```